# SQL WHERE command inadverently checking to see if variable is equal to the column name rather than column value

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a command:

`SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE word = "word";`

But this is matching all of the rows. I just want it to match the rows where the word column contain the value "word"

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE word = 'word'
```

[SQLFiddle for answer](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/a53a0/1), and [SQLFiddle for question](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/a53a0/2).  FWIW, I duplicated your results, with the second SQLFiddle, but not the first.

Comment: I don't get it. Isn't it the same except for single vs double quotes?

Comment: @oxuser From https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html: _A keyword in single quotes is a string literal. A keyword in double-quotes is an identifier._

Comment: Howver, SQLite is flexible. If you use double quotes around a string, but it isn't recognized as an identifier, it will treat it as a string literal. So you can use double quotes most of the time, but not this time because it matches a column name.

Comment: Also from [SQLite expressions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html): *A string constant is formed by enclosing the string in single quotes (').*